# Can't Update User's Profile

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a program . In this program the user can login and change their details in the user's profile. The details are :username,password,email.My code is:

Profile.php

```
<?php
include_once "db_connection.php";
if (isset($_GET['user_name']))
{
$user_name = $_GET['user_name'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '$user_name' ")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row)
{
$user_email = $row['user_email'];
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
}
?>
```

And the form in profile.php is:

```
<form id="form1" action="updateprofile.php" method="post" class="form">
<fieldset class="form-inline">
<div class="form-col-3-8" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:20px;"align="center">
<label>UserName<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-col-2-8" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:20px;"align="center">
<label>Password<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
</div>
<div class="form-col-3-8" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:20px;"align="center">
<label>E-mail<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" />
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="da-button-row">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
```

And finally the updateprofile.php is:

```
<?php
include_once "db_connection.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_name2 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_name']));
$password =  mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));
$passwordmd = md5($password);
$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_email']));
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_name='$user_name2', user_email='$user_email' ,user_password_hash='$passwordmd' WHERE user_name LIKE '$user_name'")
or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

All works fine, but when I push Submit the details doesn't change in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1 note is that everything relies on the post so there is not check as to whether this user can update the details.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: I could also easily set my user name to something silly and overwrite every single record in your users table.  You never want to use `LIKE` unless you're doing substring matches.  Further, using a changeable value as a table's primary key is *insane*.

Comment: Thank for your suggestions .I'm very new in php and I'm still learning.